# Copy build artifacts to s3 bucket using Buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to understand codebuild recently. I am trying to copy the build artifact to S3 bucket. I seen in one of my project's they are copying the files to S3 bucket using the command "aws s3 cp" instead of using the artifact phase.

1. Cant we achieve this using the artifact phase after post build phase instead of copying using "aws s3 cp" command in post build phase?
2. What is the purpose of the artifacts phase in Buildspec.yml?
3. Can we have Buildspec.yml without artifacts?

```
version: 0.2
env:
    variables:
        CACHE_CONTROL: "100"
        S3_BUCKET: animation-project
        BUILD_ENV: dev
phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            nodejs: 10
        commands:
            - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
            - echo environment printing ${STAGE}
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
    build:
        commands:
            - echo Build started on `date`
            - ng build --configuration=${BUILD_ENV}
           # - ng test
            - echo build completed
    post_build:
         commands:
            - echo Post Build Started successfully on `date`
            - aws s3 cp dist/* s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive --acl public-read --cache-control "max-age=${CACHE_CONTROL}"
            - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
    files:
        - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'dist*'
    discard-paths: yes
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.